# Is there an efficient algorithm for fuzzy deduplication of string lists?

Tags: algorithm, duplicates

For example, I have a long list of strings, each string has about 30-50 characters, and I want to remove strings that are similar to some other string in that list (leaving only one occurrence from a family of duplicates).

I looked at [various string similarity algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures), for example, Levenstein distance and the method presented in [this article](http://www.catalysoft.com/articles/StrikeAMatch.html). They do work, but it's painfully slow - the best algorithm I came up with exhibits O(n^2) complexity and takes ~1.5s to process list with 3000 strings.

Is there some fast way to deduplicate those lists?

Comment: If you don't want to apply any specific similarity measurements you can implement hash function that would represent content of string. Let say two strings are similar if they contain same letters with same quantity. Code a string with hash function that represent this property and check if you have already coded any string with the same hash, if so you can eliminate it.

Comment: @stuhlo - consider these two strings: "apple tree" and "apple trees". They are quite similar, yet they do not contain the same letters. On the other hand, they have an edit distance of 1.

Answer (score 2):

If your measure of similarity is strong (e.g. Levenshtein distance 1), then you can process your string list in order, generating all possible "close" strings to the current string and looking up that close string in your hashtable.  If it is there, skip the original string.  If not, output it and add it to the hashtable.

This algorithm depends on being able to generate all close strings to a string, and there not being too many of them.  (This is what I mean by "strong" above.)

As a possible optimization, you could store more than just the original strings in the hashtable.  For instance, if you wanted Levenshtein distance 3, you could store all strings distance 1 from your outputted strings in the hashtable, then look up distance 2 strings when checking a new string.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs frequently when matching  DNA strings(or re-assembling fragments). The first approach would be to split up the strings into `kmer`s, substrings, with *say* 4 adjacent letters. So

```
abcdefgh
```

Would become:

```
abcd + bcde + cdef + defg + efgh
```

For the complete *dictionary*, these substrings can be enterered into a hashtable, each carrying as a *payload* a list of the original strings (their numbers) that contain them (and possibly the offset where they can be found)

To search, treat the *string under test* the same as the *dictionary*, and look its fragment up in the hashtable. Now a *hit* will result in all five fragments to be found, with the correct offsets. A partial hit will yield fewer than five fragments, but with the correct offsets.

Of course a lot of false-negative hits will result from the search, but by combining (logical AND) of the *inverted index* lists, and by only selecting the hits at *about* the right index, things get unique pretty fast.

For the problem size in the OP's question the running time would probably be a few (tens of ) milliseconds.

BTW: As a side effect of this method, substitutions will behave almost the same as indels. In the example they would spoin one (at the ends) to four (in the middle) kmer-matches. For larger strings this is not a problem, for small strings (like in the example it is (and you could use smaller fragments)

Update: I just read the link, and it appears they use 2-mers, too (and throw some statistics at it)

Comment: It seems I'm doing something wrong, because I tried almost exactly this approach and got those slow times. I'll try again.