# Mongodb compare two strings to find the any match on words

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, string-comparison

I need to compare two tables and find the duplicates and merge it based on the name matches. Have 2 collections on mongoDB

Collection A
name : 'abc company ltd'

Collection B
name: 'abc comp. limited'

both are same company, but keyed in different tables by different persons.

I want to find all these kind of duplicates and merge into one.

thanks

Comment: That is a vague question. Problem is of fuzzy duplicate removal. check these out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196053/fuzzy-matching-deduplication-in-less-than-exponential-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851582/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-for-fuzzy-deduplication-of-string-lists. This problem is not related to mongo, its a totally different field

Comment: Thanks for your support, i think, it will help.

Comment: Could you post what your sought after end result is

Comment: I found two ways to achieve this. first way using Python. refer this link. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/full-text-search-in-mongodb--cms-24835. Other way, using mongo aggregation. I will post in details after i completed.

Comment: I tried another way too. http://tekpot.blogspot.com/2017/06/mongodb-using-aggreagte-and-text-search.html